# specman e lists constraints references

Tags: verification, specman

i am trying to do the following :

```
unit parent {
              sons: list of sons is instance;
              grands: list of grands is instance;

              keep sons.size() == 4;
              keep grands.size() == 4;
};

unit sons {
            grands:list of grands is instance;
            keep grands == get_enclosing_unit(parent).grands.all( .id > 3 );

           //this is not working
           keep for each in grands {
              it.parent_age == 70;
           };
};

unit grands {
           id: uint;
           parent_age:uint;
};

extend sys {
   p : parent is instance;
   run() is also {
      print p;
      for each (s) in p.sons {
         print s;
      };
      for each (g) in p.grands {
         print g;
      };

   };
};
```

in other words , i want the sons list to point to a part of the parents list , but still be able to constraint(the not working part) the list of grands from the sons unit/struct.

With PGen constraint engine on 9.20, the above code produces:

```
Starting the test ...
Running the test ...
  p = parent-@0: parent   e_path: sys.p
  hdl_path:
        ----------------------------------------------  @tmp
0       sons:                           (4 items)
1       grands:                         (4 items)
  s = sons-@1: sons   e_path: sys.p.sons[0]
  hdl_path:
        ----------------------------------------------  @tmp
0       grands:                         (empty)
  s = sons-@2: sons   e_path: sys.p.sons[1]
  hdl_path:
        ----------------------------------------------  @tmp
0       grands:                         (empty)
  s = sons-@3: sons   e_path: sys.p.sons[2]
  hdl_path:
        ----------------------------------------------  @tmp
0       grands:                         (empty)
  s = sons-@4: sons   e_path: sys.p.sons[3]
  hdl_path:
        ----------------------------------------------  @tmp
0       grands:                         (empty)
  g = grands-@5: grands   e_path: sys.p.grands[0]
  hdl_path:
        ----------------------------------------------  @tmp
0       id:                             4107502109
1       parent_age:                     3829340118
  g = grands-@6: grands   e_path: sys.p.grands[1]
  hdl_path:
        ----------------------------------------------  @tmp
0       id:                             3657005019
1       parent_age:                     2354335776
  g = grands-@7: grands   e_path: sys.p.grands[2]
  hdl_path:
        ----------------------------------------------  @tmp
0       id:                             3238917208
1       parent_age:                     336300761
  g = grands-@8: grands   e_path: sys.p.grands[3]
  hdl_path:
        ----------------------------------------------  @tmp
0       id:                             1416976666
1       parent_age:                     2212224392
```

With IntelliGen constraint engine on Specman 9.20, the above code produces:

```
Starting the test ...
Running the test ...
  p = parent-@0: parent   e_path: sys.p
  hdl_path:
        ----------------------------------------------  @tmp
0       sons:                           (4 items)
1       grands:                         (4 items)
  s = sons-@1: sons   e_path: sys.p.sons[0]
  hdl_path:
        ----------------------------------------------  @tmp
0       grands:                         (4 items)
  s = sons-@2: sons   e_path: sys.p.sons[1]
  hdl_path:
        ----------------------------------------------  @tmp
0       grands:                         (4 items)
  s = sons-@3: sons   e_path: sys.p.sons[2]
  hdl_path:
        ----------------------------------------------  @tmp
0       grands:                         (4 items)
  s = sons-@4: sons   e_path: sys.p.sons[3]
  hdl_path:
        ----------------------------------------------  @tmp
0       grands:                         (4 items)
  g = grands-@5: grands   e_path: sys.p.grands[0]
  hdl_path:
        ----------------------------------------------  @tmp
0       id:                             619055518
1       parent_age:                     4122406610
  g = grands-@6: grands   e_path: sys.p.grands[1]
  hdl_path:
        ----------------------------------------------  @tmp
0       id:                             2908565159
1       parent_age:                     1741309063
  g = grands-@7: grands   e_path: sys.p.grands[2]
  hdl_path:
        ----------------------------------------------  @tmp
0       id:                             3091108084
1       parent_age:                     1231835435
  g = grands-@8: grands   e_path: sys.p.grands[3]
  hdl_path:
        ----------------------------------------------  @tmp
0       id:                             1717477430
1       parent_age:                     937745175
No actual running requested.
Checking the test ...
Checking is complete - 0 DUT errors, 0 DUT warnings.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have generation order conflicts:

- The `sons.grands` list is populated, depending on the `grands.id` field, which means you have to generate the `grands` list first.
- The `grands.parent_age` depends on the `sons` `parent_age == 70` constraint, which means you have to generate the `sons` list first.

The easiest and most straight forward way to solve *this* code issue ( and I know you're giving a dumbed down example) is :

```
extend parent {
   keep for each (g) in grands {
      ( g.id > 3 ) => g.parent_age == 70;
   };
};
```

After more testing, I'm pretty certain its a constraint ordering issue in combination with the method invocations. The Specman generator doesn't follow through the constraints on the `sons'` `grand` list constraint, unless you set those pointers without doing a method call.

```
<'
unit parent {
   sons: list of sons is instance;     // <-- swapped these two lines
   grands: list of grands is instance; // <-- to do constraint ordering in IntelliGen
                                       //     even though Cadence says you don't need
                                       //     to
   keep for each (s) in sons {
      s.grands == grands; -- .all( .id > 3 ); -- removed the 'all' and 'get_enclosing_unit' invocation
   };

   keep sons.size() == 4;
   keep grands.size() == 4;
};

unit sons {
   grands:list of grands is instance;
   --keep grands == get_enclosing_unit(parent).grands.all( .id > 3 );

   //this is not working
   keep for each in grands {
      it.parent_age == 70;
   };
};       

unit grands {
   id: uint;
   parent_age:uint;
};

extend sys {
   p : parent is instance;
   run() is also {
      print p;
      for each (s) in p.sons {
         print s;
      };
      for each (g) in p.grands {
         print g;
      };
   };
};   
'>
```

Using *IntelliGen* ( doesn't work with PGen ):

```
Starting the test ...
Running the test ...
  p = parent-@0: parent   e_path: sys.p
  hdl_path:
        ----------------------------------------------  @tmp
0       sons:                           (4 items)
1       grands:                         (26 items)
  s = sons-@1: sons   e_path: sys.p.sons[0]
  hdl_path:
        ----------------------------------------------  @tmp
0       grands:                         (26 items)
  s = sons-@2: sons   e_path: sys.p.sons[1]
  hdl_path:
        ----------------------------------------------  @tmp
0       grands:                         (26 items)
  s = sons-@3: sons   e_path: sys.p.sons[2]
  hdl_path:
        ----------------------------------------------  @tmp
0       grands:                         (26 items)
  s = sons-@4: sons   e_path: sys.p.sons[3]
  hdl_path:
        ----------------------------------------------  @tmp
0       grands:                         (26 items)
  g = grands-@5: grands   e_path: sys.p.sons[3].grands[0]
  hdl_path:
        ----------------------------------------------  @tmp
0       id:                             4093923439
1       parent_age:                     70 
[snip]
```

You might have to look into using `pre_generate()/post_generate()` directly.  You can also look into Cisco's `csco_config` package that they open sourced [(here)](http://www.cadence.com/community/forums/T/10033.aspx).  We use that package to do weird constraints and constraint propagation in our environment.  However, most constraints are top-down, whereas your example seems to be about peers modifying each other.

One other design note.  5 levels of lists constraining each other is a bit of a maintenance issue.  Ideally, each level should only know about its child lists and its parent lists at the most.  Providing a field and then rippling that field down into lower levels will insulate each level from having to know about all the other levels.  However, I know there are reasons to violate design guidelines :-)

Comment: my problem is a lot more complicated , so i want to be able to write down the constraints in both parent and son , imagine that you have 5 different levels of nested lists , it would be almost impossible to write the constraints in the parent only

Comment: yeah, I imagine.  I've updated my answer to try to solve it again, but if things are too complex, sometimes Specman can't figure out how to do the constraint order or it stops at a method boundary.  Even with IntelliGen, though IntelliGen does a lot better.

Comment: keep for each (s) in sons {
      s.grands == grands; -- .all( .id > 3 ); -- removed the 'all' and 'get_enclosing_unit' invocation
   };

i think this will not work..., since i want in each son the list to be different...

Comment: Can you generate each sons' list programmatically without methods?

keep sons[0].grands == {grands[0]; grands[2]};
keep sons[1].grands == {grands[2]; grands[3]};

You should ask cadence support.  http://support.cadence.com

Comment: can you give me an example of doing that ? in some kind of for each loop , for example : keep for each in ... { parent[index].id > 3 => grand[..] == .. } ?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure how you do it aside from naming specific indices.